# Can we calculate double integrals without drawing the sketch?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I found it very hard to draw the sketch so my question is can we solve the question numerically without drawing the sketch ?

For example I have a question 
 $$\iint_D \arctan{\frac{y}{x}}\,dxdy$$
where $D$ is domain bounded by $x^2+y^2=1$, $x^2+y^2=4$, $y=x$, $y = \sqrt{3}x$.

Comment: why you downvote it @Matti P. ??

Comment: I didn't, it was someone else

Comment: Ok anyway please answer to my question

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but to prevent more downvotes you should show an attempt.

Comment: Solving a double integral when the limits are explicitly given is easy. Solving it on a domain requires figuring out the limits that is very difficult to do without a physical or mental sketch of the domain. In your case, however, you can simplify the integral and the domain by using polar coordinates

Comment: I did it while sketching a graph . but i am asking . is there any to find it numerically ?

Comment: Those boundary curves form the borders of two section of an annulus. One in the first quadrant and another in the third. Possibly only one component is intended? Hint: $\arctan(y/x)=\phi$ in the first quadrant and $\phi\pm\pi$ in the third (the sign depending on the choice of range of $\phi$) .

Comment: But, yes, you definitely should use the polar coordinates here. And, yes, I believe in drawing pictures in cases like these. The reason is that in applications, particularly those originating in physics, the boundaries are defined visually rather than using equations. If you cannot figure out the boundaries from a given image, you absolutely must practice that process.

Comment: Friendly reminder: if you don't include your own attempt, then this question post will likely be closed as off-topic. It seems that you'd like to see an algebraic approach in figuring out the integration limits (somehow you keep using the term "numerically"). What you have tried on the algebraic front? There are definitely some basic steps you can take on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will eventually have to make a physical or mental sketch of the domain to figure out the limits of integration. You can try to simplify the given equations through some kind of substitution. Polar coordinates work well here.

Keep $x^2+y^2=r^2,\theta=\arctan(y/x)$.

The domain $D$ is flanked by $r=1,r=2,\theta=\pi/4,\theta=\pi/3$. This is pretty simple to sketch.

[image: Figure]

The integral in the first quadrant becomes$$\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/3}\int_1^2\theta rdr~d\theta$$

Comment: thanks . but sorry for the stupid question i am a beginner i found the sketching very hard to draw .

Comment: @Hamas.S If you are not familiar with graphing polar curves, look [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PolarCoordinates.aspx).

Comment: Ok Thanks @ShubhamJohri

Comment: @Hamza.S Note that I used polar coordinates for ease of integration. The integrand $\arctan(y/x)$ is fairly difficult to integrate in Cartesian coordinates. In polar coordinates, it reduces to a mere $\theta$ in the first quadrant. For the purpose of drawing the sketch, it is equally easy to observe that in the Cartesian system, the first two equations represent circles centred at $(0,0)$ with radii $1,2$ respectively while the the latter represent straight lines passing through $(0,0)$ and inclined at $45\deg,60\deg$ in the anticlockwise direction with the positive $x$ axis respectively